# Receiving streams from two RTP stream sources, stacking them and sending to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I have two RTP sources (they will be more in the future, but I am starting with these two), sent from two different source in a Janus server. Each input has video and audio, which received at a different port each.

I am able to receive these inputs, create a mosaic, and then send the result to a .mp4 file. However, if I try to send the resulting mosaic to a RTMP endpoint (Youtube, in this case), I start having issues, I guess that due to synchronization related problems. In Youtube, I sometimes receive the content, for a few seconds, then it is lost, it comes back...

This is the expected schema:

```
RTP1 
           \
              >> ffmpeg --> RTMP
           /
RTP2
```

This is what I have up to this point. I've tried with other configurations but, in general, the obtained errors are always the same.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg \
  -vsync 1 -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -analyzeduration 60M -probesize 60M -i ../janus1.sdp \
  -vsync 1 -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -analyzeduration 60M -probesize 60M -i ../janus2.sdp \
  -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency \
  -g 60 -keyint_min 30 -sc_threshold 0 -dts_delta_threshold 0 \
  -b:v:0 1000k -profile:v:0 baseline \
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
  -filter_complex \
    "
        [0:v]fps=fps=30, setpts='PTS-STARTPTS', showinfo, scale=320x480[vid1];
        [1:v]fps=fps=30, setpts='PTS-STARTPTS', showinfo, scale=320x480[vid2];
        [vid1][vid2]hstack
    " \
  -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 \
  -strict experimental \
  -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/####-####-####-####"
```

As you can see, I'm just ignoring audio at this point, until I reach something acceptable.

janus1.sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=RTP Video
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 56.15.102
m=audio 10033 RTP/AVP 111
a=rtpmap:111 OPUS/48000/2
m=video 10038 RTP/AVP 98
a=rtpmap:98 VP8/90000
a=fmtp:98
```

janus2.sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=RTP Video
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 56.15.102
m=audio 10043 RTP/AVP 111
a=rtpmap:111 OPUS/48000/2
m=video 10048 RTP/AVP 98
a=rtpmap:98 VP8/90000
a=fmtp:98
```

The output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] Keyframe missing
Input #0, sdp, from '../janus1.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTP Video
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: vp8, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240, 250 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfc18e0] Keyframe missing
Input #1, sdp, from '../janus2.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTP Video
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #1:1: Video: vp8, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240, 250 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (vp8) -> fps (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (vp8) -> fps (graph 0)
  hstack (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] config in time_base: 1/30, frame_rate: 30/1
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] config in time_base: 1/30, frame_rate: 30/1
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] config out time_base: 0/0, frame_rate: 0/0
[libx264 @ 0x5653cd039a80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x5653cd039a80] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x5653cd039a80] 264 - core 148 r2795 aaa9aa8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=7 lookahead_threads=7 sliced_threads=1 slices=7 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=60 keyint_min=30 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=1000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/####-####-####-####':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTP Video
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 1000 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:F4E5B94F plane_checksum:[8C29DC23 43B75F12 2BE57E0B] mean:[191 110 125] stdev:[41.2 16.5 9.8]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:D37F5C42 plane_checksum:[A893D213 463ECB0C 8B5DBF05] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.5 6.4]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   1 pts:      1 pts_time:0.0333333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0E45C2B4 plane_checksum:[F0A9D56F 0AA36785 F68785B1] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   1 pts:      1 pts_time:0.0333333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:F21C5088 plane_checksum:[7A6BC3C0 A9AECD99 3A6CBF11] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.5 6.5]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   2 pts:      2 pts_time:0.0666667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:BAA1BB62 plane_checksum:[87D6D467 C7C364A8 D3448244] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   2 pts:      2 pts_time:0.0666667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9F5B4FBD plane_checksum:[5BD1C286 51A3CDAF F2AFBF6A] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.5 6.5]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   3 pts:      3 pts_time:0.1     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:3D1FC211 plane_checksum:[0814D45D 5E1065DD 8F4B87C8] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   3 pts:      3 pts_time:0.1     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:CB224DBF plane_checksum:[8808BF7A C33ECE71 CA14BFB6] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.5 6.5]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   4 pts:      4 pts_time:0.133333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0164C04F plane_checksum:[0B95D27F FE7F665A 32DD8767] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   4 pts:      4 pts_time:0.133333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:13DA5549 plane_checksum:[066DC641 B2D4D007 D641BEE3] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.5]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   5 pts:      5 pts_time:0.166667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:A147BC54 plane_checksum:[7F2DD24D DC486696 3A138362] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   5 pts:      5 pts_time:0.166667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:66234E4A plane_checksum:[A450C1BA ABDECF58 1B72BD1A] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   6 pts:      6 pts_time:0.2     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:F57FB95F plane_checksum:[2A4ED268 DCD86486 C8BF8262] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   6 pts:      6 pts_time:0.2     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:98A74DA6 plane_checksum:[BF43C14D 899ACEBD A2AABD7E] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   7 pts:      7 pts_time:0.233333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:C72EB5E6 plane_checksum:[43AECC97 FED3639A 304585A6] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   7 pts:      7 pts_time:0.233333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:EB19565A plane_checksum:[DD7ECA0D 1D36CEA4 C9CEBD8B] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   8 pts:      8 pts_time:0.266667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0136B3C5 plane_checksum:[048ECA46 22BE64D2 A282849E] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   8 pts:      8 pts_time:0.266667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:95D15554 plane_checksum:[86D7C8AA 01E7CF5E 7382BD2E] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:   9 pts:      9 pts_time:0.3     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:27F5AF6C plane_checksum:[6F29C6CB 451C6510 41D08382] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:   9 pts:      9 pts_time:0.3     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:1AAF59BA plane_checksum:[41D6CA7F 281DD14C 768FBDD1] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  10 pts:     10 pts_time:0.333333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:39FFB2C7 plane_checksum:[A07ECC0D EBDD643A 572B8271] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  10 pts:     10 pts_time:0.333333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:54645C10 plane_checksum:[D7F9CE99 1F75CF59 FC3FBE00] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.3 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  11 pts:     11 pts_time:0.366667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:8B94AB48 plane_checksum:[46D0C31C 61E563C5 5A158458] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  11 pts:     11 pts_time:0.366667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:4D0E63C6 plane_checksum:[EFA4D36E F6A4D1BA 9817BE80] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  12 pts:     12 pts_time:0.4     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0A30B0D7 plane_checksum:[9EFAC924 B58263A5 A85B83FF] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  12 pts:     12 pts_time:0.4     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:FB9069BB plane_checksum:[F855DBFE 4B7ED075 7A72BD2A] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  13 pts:     13 pts_time:0.433333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:F03AA8F0 plane_checksum:[E8C7C544 C72262EA 614B80B3] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.2 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  13 pts:     13 pts_time:0.433333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:5A2C6F58 plane_checksum:[ED4CE19C 9293D0DC A8CCBCC2] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  14 pts:     14 pts_time:0.466667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D038AE51 plane_checksum:[E340C87A C7C36271 FAFE8357] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  14 pts:     14 pts_time:0.466667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0FB9779A plane_checksum:[E00FE83A F137D1D5 477CBD6D] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  15 pts:     15 pts_time:0.5     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:AC60BB98 plane_checksum:[02A1D4F7 290F6442 67D18250] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  15 pts:     15 pts_time:0.5     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:215F7C53 plane_checksum:[8C81ED1A C6AAD2C0 8F5DBC5B] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.2 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  16 pts:     16 pts_time:0.533333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:4BEDAB8A plane_checksum:[A2DEC60F 6E5E6397 B0B581D5] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  16 pts:     16 pts_time:0.533333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:3A3E8040 plane_checksum:[0315F1F8 3174D1B7 2FB9BC73] mean:[130 119 129] stdev:[37.1 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  17 pts:     17 pts_time:0.566667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:6077B20C plane_checksum:[AC8BC9BF 81C163EB CA518453] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  17 pts:     17 pts_time:0.566667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:57B787E7 plane_checksum:[B696F787 F0B4D37F 3FAABCC3] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.1 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  18 pts:     18 pts_time:0.6     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:EEF7B3A0 plane_checksum:[74FECE16 FAF96314 F7B28267] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  18 pts:     18 pts_time:0.6     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:38A09124 plane_checksum:[3072012D 4A29D269 F5BFBD7F] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.1 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  19 pts:     19 pts_time:0.633333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9360AFBB plane_checksum:[40DACAD1 8CEF6364 57B58177] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  19 pts:     19 pts_time:0.633333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:0A3094DA plane_checksum:[61AC04F3 0DD0D267 4353BD71] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.1 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  20 pts:     20 pts_time:0.666667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D670AA5B plane_checksum:[F4E9C4BC F34C627C FFB68314] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  20 pts:     20 pts_time:0.666667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:DD6696B6 plane_checksum:[9B9B089E 7DA2D0AD A01DBD5C] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.1 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  21 pts:     21 pts_time:0.7     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:36F2AACD plane_checksum:[87E7C3EE 1DFC6345 773B838B] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.3 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  21 pts:     21 pts_time:0.7     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:9D6C9A99 plane_checksum:[EC270D54 4F5ACF5C 313FBDDA] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  22 pts:     22 pts_time:0.733333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:BFDF9868 plane_checksum:[9A8BB115 8C3C630D B3E88437] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.4 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  22 pts:     22 pts_time:0.733333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:72D3A425 plane_checksum:[A26314FB DE46D1E5 7609BD36] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  23 pts:     23 pts_time:0.766667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:66DC71DB plane_checksum:[76318C23 5C5A6183 34B68426] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.6 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  23 pts:     23 pts_time:0.766667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:A11CA30B plane_checksum:[E7B31569 F3E2D15B 41FEBC38] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  24 pts:     24 pts_time:0.8     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D4784FC6 plane_checksum:[11AE6772 CAD361D1 B5928674] mean:[191 111 125] stdev:[41.8 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  24 pts:     24 pts_time:0.8     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:AC5EA565 plane_checksum:[DDB0166C CAFCD1A5 0606BD45] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  25 pts:     25 pts_time:0.833333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:B24331EF plane_checksum:[DB1F485A CED962E3 9C7E86A3] mean:[190 111 125] stdev:[42.1 16.6 10.0]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  25 pts:     25 pts_time:0.833333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:8D38A9CF plane_checksum:[32531B72 8656D0A2 0C38BDAC] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  26 pts:     26 pts_time:0.866667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:65A90642 plane_checksum:[A79820BC 09C0602C E1C0854B] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[42.3 16.6 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  26 pts:     26 pts_time:0.866667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:35FFA9D8 plane_checksum:[A4891AD7 A712D15D 2D1ABD95] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  27 pts:     27 pts_time:0.9     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:1F26DC58 plane_checksum:[BBA5FB31 89185FB2 B96D8166] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[42.6 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  27 pts:     27 pts_time:0.9     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:3028AF2C plane_checksum:[17DE1FE2 44D1D263 B160BCD8] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  28 pts:     28 pts_time:0.933333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:FAB7B02C plane_checksum:[72DCD0DE 2B565E62 C77780DD] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[42.8 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  28 pts:     28 pts_time:0.933333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:DF85B2AD plane_checksum:[15BF21BE 83CFD21E 63C0BEC2] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  29 pts:     29 pts_time:0.966667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:A839AC77 plane_checksum:[5D6ECD35 23D65E46 EC8A80ED] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[42.8 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  29 pts:     29 pts_time:0.966667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:8D97B4EF plane_checksum:[015524DA 417BD156 80A8BEB0] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  30 pts:     30 pts_time:1       pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:CC96AC7C plane_checksum:[3302CD24 AB5A60A4 16067EA5] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[42.9 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  30 pts:     30 pts_time:1       pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:3365B4F6 plane_checksum:[3A0624DC F7ADD133 4D0BBED8] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  31 pts:     31 pts_time:1.03333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:BD86A438 plane_checksum:[31D2C468 5BCC609E 8E947F23] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[43.0 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  31 pts:     31 pts_time:1.03333 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D8DFBA9E plane_checksum:[5D1F2AC2 9129D18B 749EBE42] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  32 pts:     32 pts_time:1.06667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:D53EAD0E plane_checksum:[8B13CE10 88C76050 36827E9F] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[43.0 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  32 pts:     32 pts_time:1.06667 pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:60B1BE5F plane_checksum:[925A2ECA 6AA2D11C A129BE6A] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] RTP: missed 364 packets
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] RTP: missed 809 packets
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfbaf40] Missed a picture, sequence broken
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfc18e0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfc18e0] RTP: missed 11 packets
[sdp @ 0x5653ccfc18e0] Missed a picture, sequence broken
[Parsed_showinfo_2 @ 0x5653cd12e200] n:  33 pts:     33 pts_time:1.1     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:F681B964 plane_checksum:[87E2DAD3 830A5F77 453E7F0B] mean:[190 110 125] stdev:[43.0 16.5 9.9]
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 0x5653cd10c880] n:  33 pts:     33 pts_time:1.1     pos:       -1 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:3894C4FD plane_checksum:[72C6330F 4DDCD200 51F9BFDF] mean:[131 119 129] stdev:[37.0 9.6 6.6]
[flv @ 0x5653cd159b00] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x5653cd159b00] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=   33 fps=6.9 q=21.0 Lsize=     392kB time=00:00:23.60 bitrate= 136.2kbits/s speed=4.94x
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Best regards,
Néstor

Answer (score 0):

Better use h264 on front side (client -> janus), to increase ffmpeg performance. Then you will have 30fps and happy rtp endpoint. When you are broadcasting vp8,it is hard for ffmpeg to decode it and then encode into h264